# How to mix textareafields and two vertical buttons with label at left in a list using sencha touch?

Tags: list, sencha-touch

what i want to do is like below:

```
/*

What i want is below(the dot is to be replaced with space):
```

..............................................................toolbar1 with just text          .
..............................................................toolbar2 with just text          .
..............................................................labeled textareafield1           .
..............................................................labeled textareafield2           .
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
..................................button1          .
...................................label       .                      ......................................................................................................
.........................................................................................................button2          .

.button3      ........................  ..........................tabbar      ...........................................................................button4. 
...........................................

```
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing like this

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    fullscreen : true,
    items : [{
        xtype :'toolbar',
        title : 'toolbar with just text'
    },{
        xtype :'toolbar',
        title : 'toolbar with just text'
    },{
        xtype :'textfield',
        label: 'TextField 1',
        name: 'TextField1'
    },{
        xtype :'textfield',
        label: 'TextField 2',
        name: 'TextField2'
  },{
        xtype :'label',
        html : 'text you want to disaply..................................'
  },{
      xtype : 'panel',
      layout : 'hbox',
      items : [{
          xtype : 'label',
          html : '....................'
      },{
          xtype : 'label',
          html : '..............................................'
      },{
          xtype : 'button',
          text : 'Button Text'
      }]
  },{
      xtype : 'panel',
      layout : 'hbox',
      items : [{
          xtype : 'label',
          html : '.................... '
      },{
          xtype : 'label',
          html : 'label Text'
      },{
          xtype : 'label',
          html : '.................. '
      }]
  }]
});
```

panel with hbox layout will do the trick.. see [this](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#cuYxQ) sencha fiddle

**UPDATE**

if you put fields in fieldset then you can set the line between fields..

or you want to create simple saparater line or image.. just put in between fields

```
{
  xtype : 'label',
  html : '<hr>'
}
```

also see [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?64435-Adding-separator-in-between-formpanel-fields) sencha form thread

Comment: How to add seperator line between the textfields?